# 406 Not Acceptable on submitting a form cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, http-status-code-406

what is the maximum post limit?(The number of elements that can be posted max through a form)I have 107 questions(All Yes No radio buttons) total.Has it got anything to do with that?Because when i remove a set of questions,it works fine.

I am submitting a form of questions in cakephp.It doesnt submits on filling all values.
In firebug net panel it shows a 406 Not Acceptable status.
Any body knows what is happening here?

The form has a set of questions.It seems that last set of question is causing the problem there.When i disable that section of questions the form submits correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what was the problem but it seems to be the problem with elements that are posted with the form.It was not working on the local server but when i uploaded it on the live server it worked fine.It seems there was some problem with some settings of the Local server(Which were unavailable to me).There are some variables like >suhosin.post.max_array_depth which are not present on the live server.Its size is set to be 100 which was exceeded in my case on local server(Note it was 107).I think the problem lies there.But now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

It would be impossible to diagnose exactly what is happening with your question, but hopefully this can help narrow it down.  (For better answers, you should provide more information and, possible, code samples.)

A [406 Not Acceptable error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) occurs when the return type sent by the server is not accepted by the web browser (a.k.a., client).  This is very rare, because most web browsers accept anything.

The most common solution I found online was to [disable Apache's ModSecurity](http://www.eticketsupport.com/installation_help_software_support/solved_406_not_acceptable-t472.0.html;msg1891#msg1891), which can lead to that error.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.The form is dynamic.And one set of questions is causing the problem.When i disable that set of questions,the form submits successfully.

Comment: what is the maximum post size?I have 107 questions(All Yes No radio buttons) total.Has it got anything to do with that?Because when i remove a set of questions,it works fine.

Comment: Max post suse varies, but it's really big (usually measured in MB).  Are you sure your script simply isn't failing?

Comment: Max post size is not the problem i think.It is the number of elements that is getting posted here(107 here).I want to know that whether there is a limit to post maximum number of elements through a form?

Comment: @OverZealous After disabling the ModSecurity, the 406 error has been fixed.